# How to add padding to placeholder text

Tags: html, css, button

The following code shows placeholder text on a button, but there is more space (leading) above the top of placeholder text than below.  I want equal spacing above and below, so I tried padding-bottom but that didn’t change the space below the placeholder text.

```
<div class="signin_text EMail_Pwd_Signin">
<input type="text" class="signup_join" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Your email address" id="email_field" name="email_field" style="width:75%;" required>
</div>

.signup_join{
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-style: ridge;
    border-color: rgb(250,250,250);
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: black;
    height: 45px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: robotoregular;
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgb(150,150,150);
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 2px; }
```

How can I add padding below placeholder text in a button if it’s not padding-bottom?

Comment: I don't understand anything. Can you try `padding:15px 0;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `height` property to `line-height` it will align the content vertically, already you have added `text-align: center`.

Instead of given `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` to placeholder u can just increase the `line-height`.Top and bottom height will be automatically configured and finally the text will be **vertically aligned**.

Check the below given code:

```css
.signup_join{
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-style: ridge;
    border-color: rgb(250,250,250);
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: black;
    line-height: 45px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: robotoregular;
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgb(150,150,150);
    padding-bottom: 20px;
        padding-top: 20px;

    letter-spacing: 2px; }

.signup_join_2{
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-style: ridge;
    border-color: rgb(250,250,250);
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: black;
    line-height: 75px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: robotoregular;
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgb(150,150,150);
    padding-bottom: 15px;
        padding-top: 15px;

    letter-spacing: 2px; }

.signup_join_3{
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-style: ridge;
    border-color: rgb(250,250,250);
    border-width: 1px;
    background-color: black;
    line-height: 120px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: robotoregular;
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgb(150,150,150);
    padding-bottom: 15px;
        padding-top: 15px;

    letter-spacing: 2px; }
```

```html
<div class="signin_text EMail_Pwd_Signin">
<input type="text" class="signup_join" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Your email address" id="email_field" name="email_field" style="width:75%;" required>
</div>

<div class="signin_text EMail_Pwd_Signin">
<input type="text" class="signup_join_2" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Your email address" id="email_field" name="email_field" style="width:75%;" required>
</div>


<div class="signin_text EMail_Pwd_Signin">
<input type="text" class="signup_join_3" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Your email address" id="email_field" name="email_field" style="width:75%;" required>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it doesn't work. For me it does. Try just `padding: 15px;`

Using padding bottom it will only apply padding below, an thus your text won't be centered. Padding (with no specification) applies it everywhere around the text.

Comment: Maybe try line-height and text-indent.

Answer (score -1):

Definition and Usage

An element's padding is the space between its content and its border.

The padding property is a shorthand property for:

```
padding-top
padding-right
padding-bottom
padding-left
```

Note: Padding creates extra space within an element, while margin creates extra space around an element.

This property can have from one to four values.

If the padding property has four values:

```
padding:10px 5px 15px 20px;
    top padding is 10px
    right padding is 5px
    bottom padding is 15px
    left padding is 20px
```

If the padding property has three values:

```
padding:10px 5px 15px;
    top padding is 10px
    right and left padding are 5px
    bottom padding is 15px
```

If the padding property has two values:

```
padding:10px 5px;
    top and bottom padding are 10px
    right and left padding are 5px
```

If the padding property has one value:

```
padding:10px;
    all four paddings are 10px
```

Note: Negative values are not allowed.